# Optimize Google Sheets script | Speed up script | Faster performance - Script hiding rows

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help to optimize a script that I use to hide rows in a sheet called Calculation. It runs fairly slow.

The script goes through all rows in a range named RangeCalculation, and depending on the contents of 4 different cells in the row (column 1, 2, 4 and 10), it either hides or shows the row.

My gut tells me that there is a way to write a datastring with all the cells to hide, and then hide them all with one call, instead of performing the hide/unhide opertion for every row - but my talents with Java is inadequate.

Anyone?

```
// HIDE ROWS IN CALCULATION SHEET
function hideRowsCalc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculation");

  var currentRange = ss.getRangeByName("RangeCalculation");
  var rangeStart = currentRange.getRow();
  var rangeEnd = currentRange.getLastRow();

          for (i = rangeStart; i < rangeEnd+1; i++) {

              if (sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == "" && sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue() == "" && sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue() == "" && sheet.getRange(i,10).getValue() == "")  {
                sheet.hideRows(i,1)  
              }
            else {
              sheet.showRows(i,1)
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: Instead of making 4 .getValue() calls per row, get all the values at once and then loop through the rows (also explained here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices)

Comment: Thanks, but what would the command look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my 'Show and hide rows' script function properly in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372743/how-to-make-my-show-and-hide-rows-script-function-properly-in-google-sheets)